# google app engine how to include directories to be deployed to worker code

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

here is my directory structure:

```
Worker/
   worker.py
   worker.yaml
SharedCode/
   sharedMoudle1.py
   sharedMoudle2.py
   ...
```

in the `worker.py` , I want to include code from the shared folder. obviously in my local computer, it works since I have the Directory.

How Do I configure the `worker.yaml` to deploy the `SharedCode` directory together with `sharedCode`??

here is my worker yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
vm: true
service: worker
env_variables:
  PYTHON_ENV: lab
network:
  instance_tag: testing
  name: olympus-dev

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: worker.app
  login: admin
```

p.s not using the the `sharedCode` , the worker works fine

Answer (score 0):

Your need to convert your directories to python modules (by adding an `__init__.py` file), and then place the `.yaml` file in your project root directory. Your final directory structure should look similar to this:

```
worker.yaml
worker/
   __init__.py
   worker.py

sharedcode/
   __init__.py
   sharedmodule1.py
   sharedmodule2.py
```

Then edit the handlers directive in your yaml, as follows:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: worker.worker.app
  login: admin
```

Here's an example on how to import code from the shared module:

```
from sharedcode.sharedmodule.py import *
```